# How can I solve this Entrance Exam problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, quadratics

This question is from NEST 2018.

Suppose ${2+ \sqrt{3}}$ and $1-i$  are roots of the equation $(x^2+px+1)(x^2-2x+q)=0$ where $p,q$ are integers and $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Then what is $p+q$ ?

Comment: Why don't you plug in these roots?

Answer (score 5):

If you substitute ${2+ \sqrt{3}}$ and $1-i$ in $(x^2+px+1)(x^2-2x+q)=0$, I obtain:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
(({2+ \sqrt{3}})^2+p({2+ \sqrt{3}})+1)(({2+ \sqrt{3}})^2-2({2+ \sqrt{3}})+q)=0
\\ ((1-i)^2+p(1-i)+1)((1-i)^2-2(1-i)+q)=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

From the first equation, I obtain: $(2+\sqrt3)(p+4)(3+\sqrt3+q)=0$, so $p=-4$. Now, plugging in the second equation, I have: $(2i-4)(q-2)=0$ and $q=2$.

In conclusion $p+q=-4+2=-2$

Comment: $p+q \neq -2$ if you substitute $(1-i)$ in $(x^2+px+1)$ and $(2+\sqrt{3})$ in $(x^2-2x+q)$

Comment: Sorry, I haven't understood what do you mean.

Comment: I am trying to say the answer does not come out to be $-2$ if $x=(1-i)$ is substituted in$(x^2+px+1)$ and $x=(2+\sqrt{3})$ is substituted in $(x^2-2x+q)$.

Comment: In fact I have substitute first in the all equation the first solution and found the value of $p$. After that in the same way I have found the value of $q$, using the second solution.

Comment: Oh... sorry, my bad. I did not read your solution properly.

Answer (score 2):

As $p,q$ are integers, the other two roots are $2-\sqrt{3}$ and $1+i$ by examining the quadratic equation. Hence our equation would be equivalent to
$$(x-(2+\sqrt{3}))(x-(2-\sqrt{3}))(x-(1-i))(x-(1+i))=0$$
$$(x^2-4x+1)(x^2-2x+2)=0$$
$$\therefore p+q=(-4)+(2)=-2$$

Comment: With Vieta's formulas you don't need the linear factorisation. You can just read out $(2+\sqrt3)+(2-\sqrt3) = -p$ and $(1-i)(1+i) = q$.

Comment: I did not understand how $2-\sqrt{3}$ and $1+i$ will be the other $2$ roots ?

Comment: Because $\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{-1}$ can only have come from the term $\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ in the quadratic formula. Hence the $\pm$ means that the corresponding root with irrational part negated must also be a root of the quadratic which produced them.